# Java 64 bit fails or hangs in 64 bit Internet Explorer 11

Tags: 64-bit, java, internet-explorer, freeze

Installed 64 bit Java for Internet Explorer. IE has "Enhanced Protected Mode" and "64-bit Processes for Enhanced Protected Mode" both enabled, and no "iexplore.exe *32" processes are running.
[Detecting Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/testvm.xml) times out. Neither does the [script](http://javatester.org/version.html) at Javatester work. The 
[auto detect driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers) at Geforce actually hangs the tab, and there is no crash dialog for it.
The exceptions site list in the java CP has been edited with "http://javatester.org", "https://www.java.com/" and "http://www.geforce.com/drivers" as has the trusted sites tab in the IE Security tab.
Anyone else with similar?

```
- Windows Version 8.1 Pro
- Java Ver 8 Update 60
- Defender 4.8.207.0 Real Time Protect turned on
- Java(tm) Plug-In 2 SSV Helper  Status  Incompatible   64-bit
- Java(tm) Plug-In 1 SSV Helper  Status  Incompatible   64-bit
- Deployment Toolkit [Oracle] 64 bit enabled but not loaded
```

Comment: What version of Windows? What version of Java? Do other 64-bit IE plugins work? Do you have any anti-malware or antivirus software on your system that tries to scan your web browser?

Comment: Question with requested details updated. No AV or MW other than Defender. Other loaded add-ons are 32 & 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Try unistalling 64-bit Java and install 32-bit version of latest Java instead. I had issues in otherwise 64-bit system trying to get IE11 and Java to communicate. Issue was fixed after I installed 32-bit version of Java.